# Html editing in Windows 10 similar to Mail app?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to read `HTML` and allow my user to edit `HTML` by providing him all the formatting options like Bold,Italic,Underline,Bullet points,etc. I also noticed that Microsoft is allowing all such formatting options in their default Outlook Mail app when we click on more in Bottom bar. Can someone please suggest is there any direct API to achieve this in Windows 10 or any third party API available in `Nuget` ?

I want to achieve like below:

[image]

Comment: Try using Rich edit box for Your mail body: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/rich-edit-box

Comment: will it have all these options but default?

Comment: You need to dig in to my friend. It may provide all the options.

Comment: ok. is there any API that provides these options directly as Microsoft has used in their mail app? Also how it differs from RichTextBox?

Comment: Refer this link https://www.componentone.com/Studio/Input-Editing/RichTextBoxUWP

Comment: is this available in default or I need to install it via Nuget?

Comment: You have to download it and and i just got know that  its not for free..

Comment: Yes I also read that its 30 day trial and not free.

Comment: Do I need to add all options manually by myself?

Comment: Got a very good article on https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-rich-editor/

Comment: Yes. But its done using RichEditBox control.

Comment: But it will read document and do the editing right, so it will be helpful. Will RichEditBox not read HTML?

Comment: It wont read HTML,You have to convert it to RTF format. This link might help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2009/09/28/converting-rtf-to-html/

Comment: @LovetoCode The conversion that you suggested is for WPF. Can you suggest same for Windows 10 UWP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a very good article to achieve my requirement on following

[RichText Editor](https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-rich-editor/)

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: When I post just a link to an article I wrote I get criticisms and down votes. People say that we are supposed to provide more than a link elsewhere.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but the article seems to edit RTF and not HTML as you wanted initially. I guess your requirements allowed RTF as an alternative? But it is a good sample code anyway... Thanks.