# UWP Webview Content Editable

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a webview in my UWP windows store app. It recognises html content and renders accordingly. Now I need this webview to be editable. Please help someone.

Comment: Please, explain, what exactly you mean?

Comment: I have content already in html format (Bold, Italics, dashed borders, all html styles). I need to view this content in html format(with styles) as is and then edit only the text within this content. Able to resolve by adding contenteditable div to the html content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a local html file which has body as contenteditable div and using WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri method [(Here's the Sample)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj38Y6U8dLRAhXFMI8KHeCFB3AQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Fwsdevsol%2F2014%2F06%2F20%2Fa-primer-on-webview-navigatetolocalstreamuri%2F&usg=AFQjCNHLES75t3v9twDU3ZSmDATk1LCz3Q&sig2=pFK_Jya1AVeuys-PYIsRAA&bvm=bv.144224172,d.c2I), navigate to this page.Then set the div's content with your string. Also refer WebView.InvokeScriptAsync and ScriptNotify to inject and retreive data from webview.

Comment: : Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the contenteditable div to the html content and able to edit the Webview with html styles as is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `WebView` is for displaying HTML content only. You'll need to use a different control for editing HTML.

Out of the box there's nothing specific for this. The nearest is the `RichTextBox` but you'll need to convert what this creates from RTF to HTML. This [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36541020/1755) points to [this guide on how to do it](https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-rich-editor/).

Comment: Thanks Matt for your suggestion. The problem in my requirement is, i have content already in html format (Bold, Italics, dashed borders, all html styles). I need to view this content in html format(with styles) as is and then edit only the text within this content. Is there anything else that can help this scenario.

Comment: @user3098151 You could try embedding a web based HTML editor (Google to find some I have no recommendations nor have I tried this) and using that within the Webview.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Will try.

Answer (score 1):

you can "inject" javascript to the webview when navigation complete.
the inject script you can do the logic you want in .and you can inject this in the NavigateComplete Event.

Answer (score 0):

WebView1.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString( "<HTML><HEAD/><BODY contentEditable='true'>Hello 2</BODY></HTML>" );

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).